# Is there any exception of apostrophe rules?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

Why is there no apostrophe 's' after “election body” in the following sentence? Congress goes to top Court over election body 'inaction' on PM's speeches.

Comment: This "sentence" appears to be a headline - headlines generally speaking aren't complete and grammatical English sentences.

Comment: Are you asking about apostrophes or possessives or noun adjuncts here? There are dozens of questions here about all three, and I’m sure you can find one which answers what you’re looking for, though I’m not sure exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they are not using it as a possessive. That is, they are not saying that the inaction belongs to the election body. But rather that it is inaction of the "election body" type. Sort of like "I'm allergic to cat dander" means I am allergic to dander that comes from cats as opposed to dander that belongs to cats.